# Passing parameters from Node.JS to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am parsing an array from an API in Node and then handling it to my HTML file so I can draw on a map some points I received from the API. I want to pass as a parameter the array so the HTML receives it. I've looked through all the other possible answers here but none worked.

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const util = require('util')
var request = require("request")

var path = require('path')

const app = express()

app.get('/_bicis', (req, res) => {

    var url = "https://nextbike.net/maps/nextbike-official.json?city=532"

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            data = body['countries'][0]['cities'][0]['places']

            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'), {data: data});
        }
    })
})


module.exports = app
```

`index.html` file

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    // When printing this line it raises an error
    console.log("RECEIVED FROM HTML" + data)
</script>
</body></html>
```

I am not using any template to generate my HTML file, should I? Can it be done with the code I have?

Comment: "I am not using any template to generate my HTML file, should I?" — Yes. That is what templates are for.

Comment: "When printing this line it raises an error" - what is the error?

Comment: @mrdeadsven — It'll be a reference error because `data` isn't declared in that program.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because `data` is only available in your Node.js environment and not inside your browser. In this case, express is only used to serve the static HTML file `index.html`. In your browser environment, the data is no longer available.

There are two methods to pass the data to your browser:

1. Use a template to generate your HTML code on the server side.
2. Move the API request to a different route, like `app.get('/_bicis/api', ...)` and use a front-end framework to make an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) call to the new route. This will request the data from your browser and you can use front-end JavaScript to build your HTML.